# Java: Variable requires Class and Interface

Tags: java, interface

I have the following classes and interfaces

```
interface R
class A extends Component implements R
class B extends JButton implements R
class C extends JPanel implements R
class D extends xyz (that extends Component) implements R
```

So I have several classes that all extend some kind of Component (more or less directly) and that all implement R.

Then I have a different class F that has variables AND methods that needs to work like this:

```
public class F {

  public TYPE myVariable;

  public myMethod void (TYPE argument) {
    //...code...
    myVariable = argument;
    actionThatRequiresComponent(argument);
    argument.actionDefinedInR();
    //...code...
  }

  public anotherMethod void () {
    //...code...
    myMethod(myVariable);
    //...code...
  }
}
```

The problem is, that TYPE has to meet two requirments: It has to be any kind of Component and has to implement the interface R. The variable has therefore the same requirements.

I'm not sure at all which approach to take? Shall I make some kind of abstract classes extending Component, implementing R? Shall I skip the requirement of interface R and just do it with try catch? Shall I work with generic classes and how do I do that when it comes to variables?
Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried declaring your generic type `T` as `<T extends Component&R>` ?

Comment: I don't get it.

Comment: Where is that `action` definition coming from? Is it a part of `R`? If so, is `R` a generic interface?

Comment: That method "action" is not defined in R but in another completely different class (let's call it class F). Also in F there must be the variable that also has the type "<T extends Component&R>".

Comment: Name `xyz` doesn't follow the Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a method that accepts a parameter that must extend `Component` and implement `R`, you can do it like this:

```
public <T extends Component & R> void myMethod(T item) {
    ...
}
```

Then you should be able to pass into your method any argument whose type extends/implements the types you specified.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer - at least it shows me, that I have been on the right path once. This is what I already have tried. But first, I was told that "on the fly" defining of types is bad programming (although I wasn't given a reason why it is bad programming) and second, I have the problem that I don't know how to define variables the same way. As I wrote above, I also need variables of that type. I cannot write public <T extends Component & R> myVariable = new C();

Comment: Why would you need to declare a variable like that? You can just declare `C myVariable = new C();` if `C` is its concrete type.

Comment: I need to store the variable that was used to call that method. So I have a variable myVariable that is empty first. After I called myMethod with any type of Component (that implements R) I will store that argument to myVariable. I also cannot make myVariable from type object as this variable might be used again for that method.

Comment: Perhaps you should post a new question, or edit this one to include all the information necessary to understand it, such as where you need this variable and how it is supposed to be used.